# FLEX: I'm looking for a component doing this

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Could you suggest me a good Flex component for the widget shown in picture ?

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/timeline.png

Functionalities:
- range selection
- scalable time period on x axis
- histograms areas

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a component, but a good example:

http://www.stretchmedia.ca/code_examples/chart_range_selection/main.html

Comment: man this is exactly what I need. Do you know where I can get the sources ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try fusioncharts . Its opensource.
http://www.fusioncharts.com/flex/gallery/

Comment: That doesn't seem to be open source at $299 / developer license.

Comment: Or more specifically, "This license allows ONE developer to use FusionCharts for Flex in multiple Adobe Flex solutions (projects) or website, but not commercial products made by ISVs." Open source doesn't mean free as in beer, it means free as in speech.

Comment: That's true - but the cost seems prohibitively high for one developer just playing around with the code, which is generally against the spirit of open source.